# TFS PREVIEW: How do I setup a hosted build controller

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild

I have read that Microsoft announce Build Service and hosted build controller as shown in image below. I have have setup TFS preview using this [article](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/).

**But When I am trying to connect my cloud service it says there no hosted control found.
Can you please tell me how to setup hosted build controller.**

[Announcing a Build Service for Team Foundation Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/03/27/announcing-a-build-service-for-team-foundation-service.aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosted Build Controller should be available by default. You shouldn't have to do anything to "set it up".

Here's what I see in my TFS Preview account.

[image]

Although TFS Preview has been having [some issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfservice/archive/2012/10/19/hosted-build-issues-10-19-2012-update.aspx) lately. On Friday, builds that were queued, were stuck in the queued status for a long time before it got picked up for compilation & deployment.

Check the status here - http://tfspreview.com/en-us/support/current-service-status/

Comment: So the Build Controller dropdownlist is empty in the popup view when you try to queue a build on the portal?

Comment: when i try to define build defination it tells there no hosted bild contorller

Comment: Based on some quick testing we did, it looks like it could be a region based restriction as I was able to set up a project on Hosted Build controller when using a brand new account created in the US.